# Save a Video file in client browser cache storage after downloading from server using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, browser, cachestorage

I am trying save a video file in client's browser cache storage after downloading from server. then i can use that video in client side only by geeting from browser memory.

> So it possible programmaticly?

I have searched lot of artice but didn't find good solution.
i know Localstorge and session storeage. so can we save video in these storage or need to use cache storage ? i have mutilple videos files to downlaod which total size will be 60MB

Comment: The storage needed would be 33% more as you would need to encode into something like base64.. to get the file use ajax and feed it into a buffer which you can then serialise and store, tbh its all not worth the hassle for 60mb

Comment: you mean, after getting video file from server, then need to convert it to base64 and store in memory ?

Comment: If you must do it, then please use [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API), not LocalStorage, but also consider why the browsers decided not to cache the media if they didn't.